# Image Resizer watermark plugin - dynamically position text and modify font size

Tags: javascript, asp.net, imageresizer

I am using [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) for an image editing tool. I have a text layer and need to dynamically modify the font size and the position via the querystring, but am unable to do so.  Is this possible?

I got the text to change, via #{key}, I'm hoping there is a similar method to adjust font size and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided CustomOverlaySample is probably a better starting point than Watermark if you have custom layout rules.

However, Watermark is pretty simple and easy to modify; and the license does permit that.